# Tracking the usage of CSS for page

Tags: html, css

If I navigate the website I'm developing I can keep track of any CSS directive that is being used in that page.

For example I could associate the directive written at line 1 of main.css to the page Index.htm

I've got a CSS file which is 4000 lines and I would like to split it.

The best way would be to separate it for pages.

Every CSS instruction which is specific to only one page could be moved.

How could I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tool like [**uncss**](http://davidwalsh.name/uncss) for every page in the app and diff the outcome to see what has been removed/not used on that page.

*Edit:*
You could automate the process a bit more using Grunt with [grunt-uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) or Gulp with [gulp-uncss](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-uncss). However, I am unsure about the diffing part.

Comment: Do you also know dust me selector for firefox? Which is more fitting to this task?

Comment: Didn't know about Dust-Me. However, with uncss you could use Grunt/Gulp to run it through your site and therefore automate the process a bit more :)

Comment: if you like to edit your answer adding some extra link on how to start this process it would be great

Answer (score 0):

You would need to copy them to a new css file, I would suggest naming each CSS file with specific naming for what the code inside actually does, such as you could have a layout css file, if all pages have the same basic layout. If particular pages have a large amount of css that is only used by them you could consolidate that all into one file. You would need to do full testing once done to ensure all pages have the cs files they need (and none they actually don't need). with 4000 lines it will be a large task but will be far more manageable in future upgrades/revisions